# Salesforce POST with both SObjects and ContentVersion

Tags: httprequest, contentversion, post

I'm trying to build functionality in Salesforce to allow a payload POST which would create multiple SObjects and ContentVersions (Images/PDFs mostly).  I've built out a custom endpoint to handle the creation/linking of the SObjects but I realized `Apex REST does not support multipart/form-data requests`.

One option I thought of is to send all SObject info via my custom POST endpoint and create a custom `Document` record (all Files are linked to a custom `Document` record that has metadata pertaining to the File itself) that contains an external ID, then send a separate POST to `/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentVersion` for the actual files and link up the newly created File to the `Document` using the External IDs.  Does ContentVersion allow custom fields/have a field for External ID?

Is there a better/easier way to handle this?

Comment: Thanks @identigral - this looks great!  Follow-on question would be: if I have a reasonable amount of logic in the current Apex Rest class, would you recommend moving that to TriggerHandlers on the objects themselves?

Comment: Sure, triggers are an option.